# PHP Bug in if-statement?

Tags: php, debugging, if-statement

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00df9cc6697316297118b6a073b0e4784fcd5ad0

How come, that in PHP the following is true?

```
if ("*" == 0) { echo "What the heck?"; }
```

This makes absolutely no sense?

Comment: Because one is a string and one is an integer so the string is cast to an integer which can only be 0 since its not a number. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: It's a string, what did you expect? Same thing with "A" https://3v4l.org/u7RhJ

Comment: "This makes absolutely no sense?" --- what makes absolutely no sense is to compare a string and a number and to expect a reasonable result back.

Comment: If you would do === it wouldn't be true